# How can I use the type system with flags to functions that are sometimes shared, and sometimes exclusive?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm working on bindings to a web service, where some of the calls take flags to return additional information. For example, getting an artist via ID can take the 'recordings' flag to return recordings of an artist, and getting a release by ID can also take the recordings flag to get all recordings of tracks on that release. However, when getting an artist you can get all releases by that artist, but this flag is not valid when you actually get a specific release.

So to encode that into the Haskell, the following should be a valid program:

```
getArtistById 5678 [ WithRecordings ]
getReleaseById 37837 [ WithRecordings ]
```

And the following should be an invalid program, and fail to build:

```
getReleaseById 739 [ WithReleases ]
```

---

I've thought of a few solutions, but I'm not sure which I should take. The first idea that came to mind was to use type classes `ArtistFlag` and `ReleaseFlag`, but this doesn't make sense for a few reasons. Firstly, `ArtistFlag f => [f]` means a list of the same flag, which is flawed. But also, the type class would imply the ability to add extra flags  in the future, which also does not make much sense - there are a finite number of flags.

My next option was separate data declarations for each end points flags:

```
data ArtistFlag = ArtistWithRecordings | ArtistWithReleases
data ReleaseFlag = ReleaseWithRecordings
```

This is kinda clunky to work with -- ideally `*WithRecordings` should always have the same name, to simplify the API for the programmer.

Finally, and this is the only option I haven't explored due to lack of knowledge, this might be solvable by HList. getArtistById should take a heterogeneous set of artist flags. I don't know how to express this in HList yet though, or even if it can do this.

Would love to hear what typing gurus have to say :)

The actual part of the API I'm implementing is at http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service/Version_2#Subqueries -- notice the `recordings` flag, etc.

Comment: I think you mean to only have the `getReleaseById 739 [ WithReleases ]` line in the "invalid program" example.

Comment: @ehird yea, thanks for catching that.

Comment: [Type Directed Name Resolution](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/TypeDirectedNameResolution) is a possible (as yet unimplemented) solution to this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking your question completely literally, this cannot be achieved with a simple list; each element in a list has the exact same type, and is independent of all the others, so there's no possibility for "action at a distance" like this.

However, the changes required to get it working at very small (indeed, much more would be required to get it working with something like HList). Here's an idea that keeps your API basically the same, but doesn't require any sort of prefixing: use type-classes to represent flags that multiple types support.

```
data ArtistFlag = ArtistWithRecordings | ArtistWithReleases
data ReleaseFlag = ReleaseWithRecordings

withReleases :: ArtistFlag
withReleases = ArtistWithReleases

class HasRecordingsFlag flag where
  withRecordings :: flag

instance HasRecordingsFlag ArtistFlag where
  withRecordings = ArtistWithRecordings

instance HasRecordingsFlag ReleaseFlag where
  withRecordings = ReleaseWithRecordings

getArtistById :: Int -> [ArtistFlag] -> IO (Maybe Artist)
getReleaseById :: Int -> [ReleaseFlag] -> IO (Maybe Release)
```

The only change to the user code is that `With` gets lowercased. This is a simple solution, and is probably the easiest and most idiomatic way to solve the problem, especially given the constraints of the external API you're interfacing with.

However, it seems to me like, under some circumstances, this could be a good opportunity to restructure your API a bit; for instance, the `getArtistById` and `getReleaseById` functions you've shown worry me. If `getArtistById 42 [withReleases]` has the same type as `getArtistById 42 []`, then there's no static guarantee that you actually get the releases back from the former call; there's presumably a `Maybe [Release]` field or similar in the result, and a program making a request for an artist with releases will have to unsafely unwrap this `Maybe` (e.g. with `fromJust`) because there's an invariant in the API that isn't encoded in the type-system.

The best solution to this probably depends on a variety of factors too localised and detailed to go into here, but it's something to think about. One additional thing that sticks out to me is that, presumably, "all the recordings by an artist" is the same thing as "all the recordings of all the releases by an artist". So, in essence, retrieving the releases along with an artist is an *optimisation*; it would be best if we could express the more "primitive" form, and have it automatically retrieve in the most efficient manner.

Of course, that might not always be attainable, and if you're trying to create a direct API, it might not even be desirable. But it's the ideal, and suggests to me that if you're willing to go to great lengths with the type system to get the nicest API possible, it might be worth considering a change of focus :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend another solution based on the assumption (perhaps faulty!) that the "flags" argument will always be a static constant. When that assumption is true, you can get a lot of leverage by passing it at the type level instead. Here's a very simple example:

```
class GetArtist  a where getArtistById  :: Int -> a
class GetRelease a where getReleaseById :: Int -> a

data Artist = Artist {- whatever data you store about an artist goes here -}
data Recording = Recording {- data about recordings -}
data Release = Release {- data about releases -}
```

Then, you can simply enumerate the return types that are valid (along with implementations, of course):

```
instance GetArtist Artist where -- ...
instance GetArtist [Recording] where -- ...
instance GetArtist [Release] where -- ...
instance (GetArtist a, GetArtist b) => GetArtist (a, b) where
    getArtistById n = (getArtistById n, getArtistById n)
-- maybe a similar instance for triples
instance GetRelease Release where -- ...
instance GetRelease [Recording] where -- ...
-- no instance GetRelease [Release]
instance (GetRelease a, GetRelease b) => GetRelease (a, b) where
    getReleaseById n = (getReleaseById n, getReleaseById n)
```

To use `getArtistById`, for example, you simply call it as `getArtistById 5678` and use the result at whichever type you needed -- `Artist`, or `(Artist, [Recording])`, or whatever.

Comment: Some of these instances require `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}`. Alternatively, you could have, say, `newtype Recordings = Recordings [Recording]` and `instance Recordings where...` instead of `instance [Recording] where...`, etc.